# Retrieve Doc ID generated by Document ID services using CSOM PowerShell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, document-id

Once we activate the `Document ID Service` from the `Site Collection Features`.

Whenever a document is uploaded in a library a Unique Document ID is generated. And this ID looks something like `PNR6U3ASXZE2-1206519163-68`. Which is a click able link and gets you to the document, irrespective whether document lies in same library or moved to some other library in future.

I would want to get this very useful `ID` and `Link` using `CSOM PowerShell` and store in a different library which contains the mapping partner documents of the original.

**Simple Question**: How to get the Doc ID and URL of a `Document` in library generated by Doc ID service using CSOM PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigating a bit I have found that there are 2 important fields of an Item. And they are as follows

1. `_dlc_DocId`: It contains simple text value such as `PNR6U3ASXZE2-1206519163-68`. Which may be useful if only we need text, but not when we need the URL too.
2. `_dlc_DocIdUrl`: This is the one in which we all should be interested, because it gives both the ID and URL. See the code below.

> **Note**: I have done this in SharePoint Online, But this can be easily done in SP2013
>   On premise too.

**First connect to SharePoint Site.**

```
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("https://somesite.sharepoint.com")
$web = $ctx.Web


# Authenticating
#
$credentials = Get-Credential
$pass =  ConvertTo-SecureString $credentials.Password -AsPlainText -Force
$ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($credentials.UserName, $pass)

# Load the object
#
$ctx.Load($web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

**Get the file object and its field Items.**

```
$ObjFile = $web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/DocLibName/File.docx")
$item = $ObjFile.ListItemAllFields
$ctx.Load($ObjFile)
$ctx.Load($item)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

**Once we get the files item fields, we can store them in values and use anywhere we need.**

```
# $item["_dlc_DocIdUrl"].Url property gives the url to the document
#
$Url = $item["_dlc_DocIdUrl"].Url

# $item["_dlc_DocIdUrl"].Description gives nothing but the unique Id, i.e. PNR6U3ASXZE2-1206519163-68
#
$Description = $item["_dlc_DocIdUrl"].Description
```